# Presence of xsd link overriding xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I am really new working with XML, XSD or XSLT.

What I am trying to do is the following:

- Output data is transferred in the XML format.
- The user can review the XML file
- The user is not used to XML and wants the view the data inside a nice table instead of XML code
- I created a XSLT file for that purpose

I am done with the XSLT file (besides adjusting the colour schema etc).
The problem I have now is that in the xml file there is a link to an external xsd file (xmlns =..). As long as this code is present the rendered XML is missing the extracted input (xsl:value-of select=...).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<Table1 xmlns="http://www.test.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

My xslt code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">  
  <tr>
    <td>
    Id of
    </td>
    <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="//idOf"/>
    </td>       
  </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What am I doing wrong?

THX!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (edited according to michael.hor257k's comment)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:test="http://www.test.xsd"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
exclude-result-prefixes="test">
```

And then add `test:` to all you accesssing your xml structure, e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="//test:idOf"/>`

The xmlns="http://www.test.xsd" is not <strike>just</strike> a "Link" in your XML but it declares the default namespace - using xsd as a file extension here may be a taste thing but you can't access the data in the XML without using it.

Comment: A few corrections: **1.** A namespace declaration is not a link **at all**. -- **2.** `exclude-result-prefixes="xsi"` should be `exclude-result-prefixes="test"` -- **3.** `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` is redundant.

Comment: 1. Yes link is the wrong description.
2. Works like a charm!

@StefanHegny
What do you mean with the content mangled into one?

THX both of you!

Comment: About the mangled content, I thought if you had several test:id0f entrys you wanted them in separate table cells and that would be a little different xslt then. Newby xslt programmers might hit that trap. But if that's not the case I apologize

Comment: I just pasted a reduced example. The other entries are just copy and paste of the whole <tr> section. 45 in total. Just bumped into another problem: I have some  `<xsl:if test_="//test:idOfMarketParticipant/ace">
  ACE
  </xsl:if>` The content is not displayed as before. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Ok found out why. If I add test: to the select etc. it just works with one path. e.g. test:idof would work but not test:idof/ace
This might be a problem because some naming is identical and I select by using the full path (not sure if "path" is the correct term for this).

Comment: Welcome to SO, F_Pfeifer, you have not accepted any of the answers given to your questions. - About the test:idof/ace - that should then be test:idof/test:ace etc. in all places, and yes, path or rather "xpath" is a correct term for this. If test is too long for you, you can safely use simply t: as namespace prefix if you declare it xmlns:t="..

Comment: That did it! Thx. I tried several things but not adding the test: before each element of the xpath.